# frame differencing in opencv

Tags: opencv, frame, cookbook

I've copied and pasted a frame differencing code from "OpenCV 2 Computer Vision
Application Programming Cookbook".
but I gave an error at

> processor.setFrameProcessor( &segmentor);" It's
>   "'VideoProcessor::setFrameProcessor' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'BGFGSegmentor *' to 'void (__cdecl *)(cv::Mat &,cv::Mat &)'

how can I fix it? 
thanks.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp >
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class VideoProcessor {
 private:
 // the OpenCV video capture object
 cv::VideoCapture capture;
 // the callback function to be called
 // for the processing of each frame
 void (*process)(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&);
 // a bool to determine if the
 // process callback will be called
 bool callIt;
 // Input display window name
 std::string windowNameInput;
 // Output display window name
 std::string windowNameOutput;
 // delay between each frame processing
 int delay;
 // number of processed frames
 long fnumber;
 // stop at this frame number
 long frameToStop;
 // to stop the processing
 bool stop;
 public:
 VideoProcessor() : callIt(true), delay(0),
 fnumber(0), stop(false), frameToStop(-1) {}
 // set the callback function that
 // will be called for each frame
 void setFrameProcessor( void (*frameProcessingCallback) 
 (cv::Mat&,cv::Mat&))          
{
 process= frameProcessingCallback;
 }




     // set the name of the video file
     bool setInput(std::string filename) {
     fnumber= 0;
     // In case a resource was already
     // associated with the VideoCapture instance
     capture.release();
     //images.clear();
     // Open the video file
     return capture.open(filename);
     }
     // to display the processed frames
     void displayInput(std::string wn) {
     windowNameInput= wn;
     cv::namedWindow(windowNameInput);
     }
     // to display the processed frames
     void displayOutput(std::string wn) {
     windowNameOutput= wn;
     cv::namedWindow(windowNameOutput);
     }
     // do not display the processed frames
     void dontDisplay() {
     cv::destroyWindow(windowNameInput);
     cv::destroyWindow(windowNameOutput);
     windowNameInput.clear();
     windowNameOutput.clear();
     }
     // to grab (and process) the frames of the sequence
     void run() {
     // current frame
     cv::Mat frame;
     // output frame
     cv::Mat output;
     // if no capture device has been set
     if (!isOpened())
     return;
     stop= false;
     while (!isStopped()) {
     // read next frame if any
     if (!readNextFrame(frame))
     break;
     // display input frame
     if (windowNameInput.length()!=0)
     cv::imshow(windowNameInput,frame);
     // calling the process function
     if (callIt) {
     // process the frame
     process(frame, output);
     // increment frame number
     fnumber++;
     } else {
     output= frame;
     }
     // display output frame
     if (windowNameOutput.length()!=0)
     cv::imshow(windowNameOutput,output);
     // introduce a delay
     if (delay>=0 && cv::waitKey(delay)>=0)
         stopIt();
     // check if we should stop
     if (frameToStop>=0 &&
     getFrameNumber()==frameToStop)
     stopIt();
     }
     }
     // Stop the processing
     void stopIt() {
     stop= true;
     }
     // Is the process stopped?
     bool isStopped() {
     return stop;
     }
     // Is a capture device opened?
     bool isOpened() {
     capture.isOpened();
     }
     // set a delay between each frame
     // 0 means wait at each frame
     // negative means no delay
     void setDelay(int d) {
     delay= d;
     }
     // to get the next frame
     // could be: video file or camera
     bool readNextFrame(cv::Mat& frame) {
     return capture.read(frame);
     }
     // process callback to be called
     void callProcess() {
     callIt= true;
     }
     // do not call process callback
     void dontCallProcess() {
     callIt= false;
     }
     void stopAtFrameNo(long frame) {
     frameToStop= frame;
     }
     // return the frame number of the next frame
     long getFrameNumber() {
     // get info of from the capture device
     long fnumber= static_cast<long>(
     capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES));
     return fnumber;
     }
     };


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // The frame processor interface
    class FrameProcessor {
     public:
     // processing method
     virtual void process(cv:: Mat &input, cv:: Mat &output)= 0;
    };

    class BGFGSegmentor : public FrameProcessor {
     cv::Mat gray; // current gray-level image
     cv::Mat background; // accumulated background
     cv::Mat backImage; // background image
     cv::Mat foreground; // foreground image
     // learning rate in background accumulation
     double learningRate;
     int threshold; // threshold for foreground extraction
     public:
     BGFGSegmentor() : threshold(10), learningRate(0.01) {}

     void setThreshold(float t) {
     threshold= t;
     }

     // processing method
     void process(cv:: Mat &frame, cv:: Mat &output) {
     // convert to gray-level image
     cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
     // initialize background to 1st frame
     if (background.empty())
     gray.convertTo(background, CV_32F);
     // convert background to 8U
     background.convertTo(backImage,CV_8U);
     // compute difference between image and background
     cv::absdiff(backImage,gray,foreground);
     // apply threshold to foreground image
     cv::threshold(foreground,output,
     threshold,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
     // accumulate background
     cv::accumulateWeighted(gray, background,
     learningRate, output);
     }
    };

     int main()
    {
     // Create video procesor instance
     VideoProcessor processor;
     // Create background/foreground segmentor
     BGFGSegmentor segmentor;
     segmentor.setThreshold(25);
     // Open video file
     processor.setInput("C:/Users/Pedram91/Downloads/Video/FLIR Systems.flv");
     // set frame processor
     processor.setFrameProcessor( &segmentor);
     // Declare a window to display the video
     processor.displayOutput("Extracted Foreground");
     // Play the video at the original frame rate
     processor.setDelay(1000./33);//processor.setDelay(1000./processor.getFrameRate());//capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
     // Start the process
     processor.run();
    }
```

Comment: instead of processor.setFrameProcessor( &segmentor); it looks like you have to use a function as a parameter there. Try processor.setFrameProcessor( &segmentor.process); but not sure whether that works. Function pointers aren't my speciality :D

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. unfortunately by adding ".process" it gives me a new error: "error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression".

Comment: try without & or read about function pointers